# Can't install Firefox

Tags: package-management, firefox, dpkg

First all Firefox tabs crashed, then I closed it and wanted to restart it.

Clicking on Firefox did nothing, trying to open it via terminal gave me these errors:

```
/bin/bash: /lib/×86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: unsupported verston 0 of Verdef record 
/bin/bash:
error while loading shared libraries: /ib/×86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: unsupported verston 6 of Verneed record
```

When trying to start Ubuntu Software via "snap-store" I got the same errors.

I thought I need to get Firefox to work at least and removed it so I can reinstall it.

It appeared in my favorites bar for a second only to disappear again with these errors:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
• Run configure hook of "firefox' snap if present (run hook "configure":
• • • • •
/bin/bash: /lib/X86_64-linux-gnu/libdl. so.2: unsupported verston 0 of Verdef record
/bin/bash: error whtle loading shared libraries: /lib/×86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: unsupported verston ® of Verneed record
• . . . - )
pkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archi/les/firefox_1%3a1snap1-Oubuntu2_and64.deb (--unpack):
new firefox package pre-instaliation script subprocess returned error exit status
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var /cache/apt/archives /firefox_1%3a1snap1-Oubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /us/bin/dokg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help? I'm kind of lost now as a first time Linux user :(

I am running 22.04 using an Intel Celeron N5105 with 16GB of RAM and a 500GB SSD. In order to get Intel Quick Sync to work for my Plex server I updated the Kernel to 6.0 and installed some Intel drivers. But that didn't seem to break Firefox because it worked fine for one day before it suddenly didn't.

Comment: How did this happen? What did you do before you had this problem?

Comment: The down-vote seems a bit harsh - if you take out the bit at the start that sounds like a rant about Ubuntu you’ll probably get more positive reception. Put a bit more detail in about your system (os & hardware), as well as how long it worked for before, and anything you’ve done recently that might have caused this (any other software installed / updates  applied immediately before this issue arose) - then I think your question is fine & should get answered.

Comment: I did nothing. Firefox's tab suddenly crashed and here we are.

Comment: So there is no information to work with.

Comment: I added some information now! Also do the error messages not contain any useful information? :(